# FiddlerCore Session through Webdriver results in nothing

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, fiddlercore

I have a Selenium Webdriver test that is working fine before I add it to my test suits namespace, but in the test suit the oSession.fullUrl is blank.

I'm scratching my head for the cause. 
I've cornered it down, to I'm getting nothing back from the Session.

```
    FiddlerCoreStartupFlags startupFlags = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8080, startupFlags);

    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
         // Test fiddler not working as this is blank
         Console.WriteLine("Session is working: " + oSession.fullUrl);
    };
```

Its starting fine:
Fiddler has started up: True
Fiddler is system proxy: True
Fiddler is listening on port 8080

I'm just getting nothing from that session.

I see a  compiler warning (but not a complier error) but I cant figure out whats might be conflicting. and it seems to use the fiddlerCord.dll.

1>CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Test\FiddlerCoreAPI\FiddlerCore.dll'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning in question means that you should be using FiddlerCore3 rather than FiddlerCore2 because you're running on the .NET Framework 3.5. It's likely not related to the problem you're having.

I don't know what you mean when you say "this is blank"-- what is "blank"?

Is there a reason that you're waiting until `AfterSessionComplete` instead of looking at the session in `OnBeforeRequest` or `OnBeforeResponse`?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try using FiddlerCore3. I'm getting an empty output to the console from oSession.fullUrl when its runs. Basically no result at all where before it would output everything it was running through. There isn't a real reason why I'm using AfterSessionComplete except it was working (outside the rest of the tests).

Comment: I'm really scratching my head about it. When I run the original test (standalone, no shared codebase) it runs fine and the end results are correct. No reason I am using AfterSessionComplete beyond it was working fine in the original test.

Comment: "No Session is working at all" is very ambiguous. Are you saying `The AfterSessionComplete event handler is not firing.`?

Comment: The handler I am not sure about. I'd like way of testing that. The contents of everything in that handler I can confirm do not ouput which is why I have the line  Console.WriteLine("Session is working: " + oSession.fullUrl); It might be the handler is not firing or for some reason its not firing when I would expect it to.

Comment: It's not firing, which means you're not capturing anything, which means that your client isn't using your FiddlerCore instance as its proxy.

Comment: I though of that but this bool is outputting as true.  bool fiddlerSystemProxy = FiddlerApplication.IsSystemProxy();
            Console.WriteLine("Fiddler is system proxy: " + fiddlerSystemProxy); Could it be a system proxy but the client is not using it? How could I check?

Comment: The bool only concerns whether or not FiddlerCore thinks it's the system proxy; that has little to do whether a client is using it. What is the client in this case?

Comment: Selenium Webdriver is creating a new Firefox browser instance. But I see the same behavior from chrome.

Comment: Selenium typically offers options that control the proxy setting of the target browser. You need these to point to `127.0.0.1:8888`.